# in a SAS data step referencing another data set without a merge?

Tags: sas

Grateful for feedback, I'm still a notice programmer. I'm trying to code the below in SAS.

I have two data sets a) and b), containing the following variables:

```
a) Bene_ID, county_id_1, county_id_2, county_id_3 etc (it's 12 months) 
b) county_ID, rural (yes/no)
```

What I would normally do is create an array in a data step:

```
Array country (12) county_ID_1- county_ID_12
```

and use by group processing on bene_ID, to output a long (normalized) data set like this:

```
   bene_id, month 1, county_id 
    bene_id, month 2, county_id
    bene_id, month 3, county_id
```

etc.

BUT, how do I access the other data set b) within a data step? to pull in the rural variable?  This is what I want:

```
bene_id, month 1, county_id, if rural = "yes"
bene_id, month 2, county_id, if rural = "yes"
bene_id, month 3, county_id, if rural = "yes"
```

I tried looking for other similar questions on this bulletin board but I wasn't even sure of the correct terms to search for. The reason I don't want to do a full merge is: how to filter on an array value? e.g. when rural = "no"?

Thanks everyone,
Lori

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example where using a FORMAT would help.  You can use your second dataset to create a format

```
data formats;
  retain fmtname 'rural';
  set b;
  rename county_id=start rural=label;
run;

proc format cntlin=formats ;
run;
```

and then use the format when processing the first dataset.

```
data want ;
  set A;
  array county_id_ [12];
  do month=1 to dim(county_id_);
    county=county_id_[month];
    rural = put(county,rural3.);
    output;
  end;
  drop county_id_: ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if this was the right approach. Very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You are transforming the data structure from wide (array form) to tall (categorical form).  This is generally known as a pivot or transpose.  The transformation turns the information stored in each array element *name* (columns) into data that becomes accessible at the row-level.

You can merge the transpose with the counties to select rural ones.

```
* 80% of counties are rural;
data counties;
  do countyId = 1 to 50;
    if ranuni(123) < 0.80 then rural='Yes'; else rural='No';
    output;
  end;
run;

* for 10 people track with county they are in each month;
data have;
  do personId = 1 to 10;
    array countyId (12);
    countyId(1) = ceil(50*ranuni(123));
    do _n_ = 2 to dim(countyId);
      if ranuni(123) < 0.15 then 
        countyId(_n_) = ceil(50*ranuni(123)); * simulate 15% chance of moving;
      else
        countyId(_n_) = countyId(_n_-1) ;
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=have_transpose(rename=(col1=countyId)) ;
  by personId;
  var countyId:;
run;

proc sort data=have_transpose;
  by countyId personId;
run;

data want_rural;
  merge have_transpose(in=tracking) counties;
  by countyId;
  if tracking and rural='Yes';
  month = input(substr(_name_, length('countyId')+1), 8.);
  drop _name_;
run;
```

If your wide data also has an additional a set of 12 columns, for say an array of amounts disbursed in each month, the best approach is to do 'DATA Step' transpose like @Tom showed, with an additional assignment inside the loop

```
  amount = amount_[month];
```